# ByVal and ByRef with reference type

Tags: vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Public Class TypeTest
    Public variable1 As String
End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim t1 As TypeTest = New TypeTest
        Test(t1)
        MsgBox(t1.variable1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test(ByVal t1 As TypeTest)
        t1.Variable1 = "Thursday"
    End Sub

End Class
```

The message box in the form_load prints: Thursday, which means that the object (TypeTest) is passed by reference.
What is the difference between using ByVal and ByRef for the t1 arguement in the function called: Test.

Comment: The default is ByVal - which means a copy of the original variable. If you need to refer to the original variable, use ByRef.

Comment: @Tony, The Default is ByRef on VBA, are you sure that ByVal is default on vb.net?

Comment: @jacouh Yes, in .NET, the default is ByVal unlike in COM development where it was ByRef. Microsoft made the change because ByVal turns out to be safer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since you declared `TypeTest` as a `Class`, that makes it a *reference type* (as opposed to `Structure` which is used to declare *value types*).  Reference-type variables act as pointers to objects whereas value-type variables store the object data directly.

You are correct in your understanding that `ByRef` allows you to change the value of the argument variable whereas `ByVal` does not.  When using value-types, the difference between `ByVal` and `ByRef` is very clear, but when you're using using reference-types, the behavior is a little less expected.  The reason that you can change the property values of a reference-type object, even when it's passed `ByVal`, is because the value of the variable is the *pointer* to the object, not the the object itself.  Changing a property of the object isn't changing the value of the variable at all.  The variable still contains the pointer to the same object.

That might lead you to believe that there is no difference between `ByVal` and `ByRef` for reference-types, but that's not true.  There is a difference.  The difference is, when you pass a reference-type argument to a `ByRef` parameter, the method that you're calling is allowed to change the object to which the original variable is pointing.  In other words, not only is the method able to change the properties of the object, but it's also able to point the argument variable to a different object altogether.  For instance:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim t1 As TypeTest = New TypeTest
    t1.Variable1 = "Thursday"
    TestByVal(t1)
    MsgBox(t1.variable1)  ' Displays "Thursday"
    TestByRef(t1)
    MsgBox(t1.variable1)  ' Displays "Friday"
End Sub

Public Sub TestByVal(ByVal t1 As TypeTest)
    t1 = New TypeTest()
    t1.Variable1 = "Friday"
End Sub

Public Sub TestByRef(ByRef t1 As TypeTest)
    t1 = New TypeTest()
    t1.Variable1 = "Friday"
End Sub
```

Comment: When the passed type is a reference type, you receive a copy of the reference (point), not a copy of the type (object) and so changes made to the copied reference are persisted back to the original object. Your explanation is only correct if the passed type is a value type. Simply saying that ByRef allows you to change the value of the original variable is not accurate. You must take into account the type that is being passed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I must not have worded my answer very clearly, because that's precisely what I was trying to say :)  Guess it's time to work or an edit.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Is that more clear now?  Or am I still making it too confusing?

Comment: *"when you pass a reference-type argument to a `ByRef` parameter, ... not only is the method able to change the properties of the object, but it's also able to point the argument variable to a different object altogether."* This sentence makes it very clear IMO. +1 for that.

Answer (score 5):

A few more examples.  One shows ByRef to ByVal forced

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tt As TypeTest = New TypeTest
    tt.variable1 = "FooBar"
    Debug.WriteLine("'1 " & tt.variable1)

    TestByVal1(tt)
    Debug.WriteLine("'2.1 " & tt.variable1)

    tt.variable1 = "FooBar"
    TestByVal2(tt)
    Debug.WriteLine("'2.2 " & tt.variable1)

    tt.variable1 = "FooBar"
    TestByRef(tt)
    Debug.WriteLine("'3 " & tt.variable1)

    tt.variable1 = "FooBar"
    TestByRef((tt)) 'note inner set of () force ref to val
    Debug.WriteLine("'4 " & tt.variable1)

    'debug output
    '1 FooBar
    '2.1 FooBar
    '2.2 Monday
    '3 Friday
    '4 FooBar
End Sub

Public Sub TestByVal1(ByVal t1 As TypeTest)
    t1 = New TypeTest()
    t1.variable1 = "Monday"
End Sub

Public Sub TestByVal2(ByVal t1 As TypeTest)
    t1.variable1 = "Monday"
End Sub

Public Sub TestByRef(ByRef t1 As TypeTest)
    t1 = New TypeTest()
    t1.Variable1 = "Friday"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

ByVal actually copies the value of the current variable and pass it to the function. By reference copies the current reference to the function. Let's take your example:

t1 is a reference variable which contains the address of the object of type TypeTest, so when you use ByVal, the address is copied to the function. Eventually you use the same object.

Where it really makes sense is, in case of basic variables like int, float etc.

Example: Int temp =0;

temp is a variable which contains the value 0, so when copied 0 is passed. If you use reference then address of temp is passed (&0) to the function.

To summarize, ByRef makes more sense only in the basic types and not complex types.