# How can I make this program more efficient by using ByVal and ByRef?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to programming in VB.NET and do not know how ByRef and ByVal could work in part of this Blackjack code! Thanks!

Here is a part of the code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If hit = 0 Then
        getCard()
        PictureBox3.Image = cImg(n)
        playertotal += value
        If playertotal > 21 And pAce >= 1 Then
            pAce -= 1
            playertotal -= 10
        End If
    End If

    If hit = 1 Then
        getCard()
        PictureBox4.Image = cImg(n)
        playertotal += value
        If playertotal > 21 And pAce >= 1 Then
            pAce -= 1
            playertotal -= 10
        End If
    End If

    If hit = 2 Then
        getCard()
        PictureBox5.Image = cImg(n)
        playertotal += value
        If playertotal > 21 And pAce >= 1 Then
            pAce -= 1
            playertotal -= 10
        End If
    End If
    hit += 1
    Label2.Text = playertotal
    If Label2.Text > 21 Then
        Label11.Text = "COMPUTER WINS!"
    End If
    If hit = 3 And playertotal <= 21 Then
        Label11.Text = "PLAYER WINS!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ByVal and ByRef with reference type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707622/byval-and-byref-with-reference-type)

Comment: Why would you think you should change and event signature?

Comment: Is there a need to use byRef or byVal?

Comment: @ElenaDBA Yes I'm required to for an assignment. But the teacher never showed us and I'm very confused as to how this will even work.

Comment: Can you modify the Button3_Click signature or do you need to use it in some other manner?

Comment: Your teacher should worry about more important things like giving controls meaningful names

Comment: Off-topic, but since you are largely doing the same operations when hit is 1,2 or 3, you should rework the true branches of your if statements to only do what is unique to that situation. Better yet, use a Select Case instead of repeated if's.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET all arguments are passed ByVal by default and this is a good thing. It provides the most efficient way of passing arguments and there really wouldn't be any mainstream reason to switch to ByRef.

When talking about ByVal and ByRef, you MUST also take into account what you are passing, which could be a Value Type or a Reference Type.

If you pass a reference type ByVal (which is the most common scenario in .NET because all instances are reference types and ByVal is the default way arguments are passed), you will receive a copy of the REFERENCE, not the VALUE. This is commonly not understood by most developers. No duplication of the passed object occurs. Only the reference to the object (the pointer) is copied.

If you pass a reference type ByRef, you will not be passing a copy of the reference, you will be passing the original reference. This might be desirable for referencing reasons, but no real performance is gained over passing the reference ByVal.

If you pass a VALUE type ByVal, you will be passing a copy of the actual VALUE. In this scenario, data is duplicated. This is generally desirable to protect the original data from becoming corrupted by the method that the data was passed to.

If you pass a VALUE type ByRef, you are passing a reference to the value and if the method that receives the data modifies it, the original data is modified.

The choices you have relate to protection of data and direct reference to objects, not performance. The .NET Framework is highly optimized for performance. Generally, it is not wise to try to optimize the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using ByRef - you pass in hit not as value but as a reference to ProcessHit procedure

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    ProcessHit(hit)

End Sub

Public Sub ProcessHit(ByRef hit As Integer)
    Select Case hit
        Case 0
            getCard()
            PictureBox3.Image = cImg(n)
            playertotal += value
            If playertotal > 21 And pAce >= 1 Then
                pAce -= 1
                playertotal -= 10
            End If
        Case 1
            getCard()
            PictureBox4.Image = cImg(n)
            playertotal += value
            If playertotal > 21 And pAce >= 1 Then
                pAce -= 1
                playertotal -= 10
            End If
        Case 2
            getCard()
            PictureBox5.Image = cImg(n)
            playertotal += value
            If playertotal > 21 And pAce >= 1 Then
                pAce -= 1
                playertotal -= 10
            End If
    End Select

    hit += 1
    Label2.Text = playertotal
    If Label2.Text > 21 Then
        Label11.Text = "COMPUTER WINS!"
    End If
    If hit = 3 And playertotal <= 21 Then
        Label11.Text = "PLAYER WINS!"
    End If
End Sub
```