# How to pass an Action(Of T) when T is ByRef

Tags: vb.net

ByVal:

```
Public Sub foo()
    bar(AddressOf baz)
End Sub

Public Sub bar(ByVal numFun As Action(Of Integer))

End Sub

Public Sub baz(ByVal num As Integer)

End Sub
```

ByRef:

```
Public Sub foo()
    bar(AddressOf baz)
End Sub

Public Sub bar(ByVal numFun As Action(Of Integer))

End Sub

Public Sub baz(ByRef num As Integer)
    ' num has been changed to ByRef above ^^^
End Sub
```

The above is fine, it results in no error. However if the parameter is changed to ByRef, as below, it throws the following error:

> Error:    Method 'Public Sub baz(ByRef Integer)' does not have a
>   signature compatible with delegate 'Public Delegate Sub Action(Of In
>   Integer)(Integer)'

The signature that it gives in the error doesn't match what I have at all - what is "(Of In Integer)(Integer)"? I'm not instantiating anything. Why the "In"? In any case, what I am really after is how to make this work. I can't change the ByRef that has to remain.

***Note: I know that i can create an explicit delegate, but I don't want to as I have several instances of this problem throughout the code and it seems like unnecessary overhead.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to make an action that just ignores the `ByRef` and receives `num`s from `bar` by value?

Comment: this is a contrived example. I'm working on a pre-existing code base with a Sub that has signature "Private Sub PopulateCylinders(ByRef ListBox As CheckedListBox, ByRef OrderID As String)" ... I can't see any reason at the moment that they are ByRef, and after some inspection I can probably change it completely. I just never encountered this problem before and if I could solve it with a bandaid that would be great - if not, then i'll get to work unraveling this thing. Edit: To answer the question, I just want to know how to pass the address of an Action that has ByRef parameters in general

Comment: If it is a one-off issue and there is no good reason for the arguments to be ByRef, then you could use an anonymous method or declared method to wrap the call to to the ByRef method.

Comment: `ByRef` is not needed for reference types if the reference parameter is not set to something else inside the method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707622/byval-and-byref-with-reference-type

Comment: You can only use a delegate of a particular type to refer to methods with a signature that matches the delegate. The `Action(Of T)` delegate has a signature with one parameter of type `T` passed by value.  Your method does not match that signature so you cannot use that delegate type to refer to it. It's that simple. `(Of In Integer)(Integer)` means that the generic type is `Integer` and it is used to pass data in only, i.e. it is `ByVal`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks your last sentence cleared up all ambiguities

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Delegate Sub MyAction(Of T)(ByRef num As T)

Public Sub foo()
    bar(AddressOf baz)
End Sub

Public Sub bar(numFun As MyAction(Of Integer))

End Sub

Public Sub baz(ByRef num As Integer)
    ' num has been changed to ByRef above ^^^
End Sub
```

---

**Update**

No way around declaring your `ByRef` `Delegate`s. This is the definition of [`System.Action(Of T)`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/action.cs,486d58da4553e12d):

```
Public Delegate Sub Action(Of In T)(obj As T)
```

so you can't use `System.Action` for `ByRef` parameters because it is already declared as `ByVal`.