# Return value gets assigned but always returns as 0

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to calculate the total count and value of orders for a customer, using the code below.

```
    Dim iOrderCount As Integer
    Dim iLineCount As Integer
    Dim cTotalGoods As Decimal
    Dim cTotalVat As Decimal
    Dim cTotalDelivery As Decimal

    Using manOrders As New CManOrders(m_dbSql)
manOrders.GetOrdersInProgress(sAccountCode, iOrderCount, iLineCount, cTotalGoods, cTotalVat, cTotalDelivery)
```

When I assign values to these variables in the `GetOrdersInProgress` subroutine, the values are being assigned correctly, which I can see when I step through the code.

```
Public Sub GetOrdersInProgress(sAccountCode As String, ByRef RET_orderCount As Integer, ByRef RET_lineCount As Integer,
                               ByRef RET_totalGoods As Decimal, ByRef RET_totalVat As Decimal, RET_totalDelivery As Decimal)

    ...

    For Each dr As DataRow In m_dbSql.getDataTable(sql).Rows
        RET_orderCount = dbToInt(dr(ORDER_COUNT))
        RET_lineCount = dbToInt(dr(LINE_COUNT))
        RET_totalGoods = dbToDecimal(dr(TOTAL_GOODS))
        RET_totalVat = dbToDecimal(dr(TOTAL_VAT))
        RET_totalDelivery = dbToDecimal(dr(2))

        Return
    Next
```

However, once I step through and move back into where the `GetOrdersInProgress` subroutine is called from, all of the values in the variables are returned correctly, except for `RET_totalDelivery` - the new one I've added to another developer's project. 
The value in the `RET_totalDelivery` variable in the `Public Sub GetOrdersInProgress...` line is correct and it's correct after the assignment, but when it reaches `Return` and the variables are then used in the parent subroutine, for some reason they're all correct except for the new one I've added, `RET_totalDelivery`. I'd understand if the value wasn't being assigned correctly, however it is.

Why would it be returning 0 all the time?

Comment: @TimSchmelter the SQL that creates the DataTable does the Sum side of things, so there will only ever be one row of data. But a good point, nonetheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, arguments passed to `vb.net` methods are passed by value, or `ByVal`. You did not specify `ByRef` in your `RET_totalDelivery` argument in `GetOrdersInProgress.`

Changes made to arguments passed by value are not retained when the method ends.

Your Sub should now be...

```
Public Sub GetOrdersInProgress(sAccountCode As String, ByRef RET_orderCount As Integer, ByRef RET_lineCount As Integer, ByRef RET_totalGoods As Decimal, ByRef RET_totalVat As Decimal, ByRef RET_totalDelivery As Decimal)
```

Comment: Note: this is only true for  `Value Types`, `Reference types` are always passed by ref. see [This](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-value-type-and-reference-type)

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton that's not true.  Reference types are also passed `ByVal` as the default.  It's just that `ByRef` and `ByVal` have a different implication, if you will, for reference types.  When a reference type is passed `ByVal`, you can change it's properties, but you can't change which object it references.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19707839/1359668) for more info and an example.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, Thank you, i didn't know that. I remember reading somewhere that reference types were always passed by ref, and as it seemed to be correct for what i was doing, I assumed it was true.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write the method as a function. Write a class to hold all the return values. Then change the method into a function with just input parameters and return the values you fetch from sql.

```
Sub Main
    Dim bl = New OrdersInProgressBusinessLogic()
    Dim ordersInProgress = bl.GetOrdersInProgress("some account code")
End Sub

Public Class OrdersInProgress
    Public Property OrderCount As Integer
    Public Property LineCount As Integer
    Public Property TotalGoods As Decimal
    Public Property TotalVat As Decimal
    Public Property TotalDelivery As Decimal
End Class

Public Class OrdersInProgressBusinessLogic

    Public Function GetOrdersInProgress(sAccountCode As String) As OrdersInProgress
        Dim ordersInProgress = New OrdersInProgress()

        ' some code here to fetch data from sql

        For Each dr As DataRow In m_dbSql.getDataTable(sql).Rows
            With ordersInProgress
                .OrderCount = dbToInt(dr(ORDER_COUNT))
                .LineCount = dbToInt(dr(LINE_COUNT))
                .TotalGoods = dbToDecimal(dr(TOTAL_GOODS))
                .TotalVat = dbToDecimal(dr(TOTAL_VAT))
                .TotalDelivery = dbToDecimal(dr(2))
            End With
        Next

        Return ordersInProgress
    End Function

    ' some other functions/subs for OrdersInProgress class

End Class
```